# How to sort NULL values last - for grouping summary rows with "group by rollup/cube"

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, rollup

When using `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`, subtotal/total rows are indicated by `NULL` values in the grouped columns. That's a nice feature, however I would expect the totals under the detail values, but `NULL`s are sorted at the beginning.

Example:

```
SELECT Year, Quarter, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM Table
GROUP BY Year, Quarter WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY Year, Quarter

Year|Quarter|Amount            Year|Quarter|Amount
----|-------|------    --->    ----|-------|------
NULL|   NULL|   120            1999|      1|    10
1999|   NULL|    40            1999|      2|    10
1999|      1|    10            1999|      3|    10
1999|      2|    10            1999|      4|    10
1999|      3|    10            1999|   NULL|    40
1999|      4|    10            2000|      1|    20
2000|   NULL|    80            2000|      2|    20
2000|      1|    20            2000|      3|    20
2000|      2|    20            2000|      4|    20
2000|      3|    20            2000|   NULL|    80
2000|      4|    20            NULL|   NULL|   120
```

How to get them at the end?

I know I could replace the `NULL` values by something which would be sorted where expected, possibly in some other column, but that's a bad workaround.

Comment: edit the question to add sample data & desired output which could help to derive the solution.

Comment: alternate solution, is to sort your NULL values first then rest.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Added example, good suggestion. But I don't understand your alternate solution. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
ORDER BY Year, Quarter
```

to

```
ORDER BY GROUPING(Year), Year, GROUPING(Quarter), Quarter
```

Explanation: this function returns 1 for total rows and 0 for all others.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and found the way to get the nulls at the bottom is:

```
SELECT Year, Quarter, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM Table
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (Year, Quarter)
  ORDER BY Year ASC NULLS LAST, Quarter ASC NULLS LAST;
```

This ensures that the sorts will be in ascending order, with the nulls at the bottom.

Comment: This is NOT T-sql (SQl-server) as the question has tagged.